# Trying to connect my android device to raspberry pi

Tags: android, mysql, raspberry-pi

I connected my android to the WIFI using this command:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Now I am trying to connect the mobile to **mysql server on raspberry pi** so that I could get the data from the raspberry pi. Should I use another command or it is the same ?

Comment: I would suggest u to create a (REST-) api (in e.g. php on the pi) to communicate with the database.

Comment: I already created a php and it is working fine but i need to create an android application